# Mouse movement distance in cm

Tags: mouse, coordinates, distance

I am coding a little program which logs my mouse activity. But now i want to go a step further. Is there anyway to get the distance your mouse has traveled (on the desk) (and not the pointer on the screen).

I have given it some thought and I am thinking of a calibration function which shows a line of 200 px. And you have to move your mouse over it, then you need to fill in how many cm the mouse has moved. this then can be used by the program to calulate the distance the mouse travels on the desk according to a 100 px scale.

But, isn't there a better/ easier way to do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would probably be to make the line longer than 200px, and to use various calibration points -- such as using a large rectangle where the user must click all four corners. If you make the rectangle as large as possible, you'll have the highest accuracy.

Of course the accuracy of your final result -- the calculated distance over time -- is also dependent upon the resolution of your tracking so that you can take into account fast moves up followed by fast moves down, for instance. Just an observation :-)

Good luck!

Comment: Roy Dictus, First of all, thanks for your quick reply. The example with the line was just to make things clear for reading here. Atleast i now know that my way of thinking was correct, and that there is probably no simple way to convert this without some kind of human calibration.